# Irreducibility of markov chains

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, markov-chains

> Let $A=(a(x,y))_{x,y\in X}$ be a finite irreduzibel nonnegative
>   matrix.
>
> Let $b,c >0$, and $\alpha=a^{(b+c)}(x,x)>0$.
>
> So
>   $a^{(n(b+c))}(x,x)\ge \alpha^n$.  And therefore $\lim
>  \sup_{n\rightarrow\infty}{a^{(n)}(x,y)^{1/n}}\ge\alpha^{1/(b+c)}>0$

I don't understand several things here:

1. Why  ist this wrong: $a^{(n)}(x,y)^{1/n}=a(x,y)$
2. I don't understand how to follow the whole 3th line.

Thanks for any kind of help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $a^{(n)}$ is the $n$th power of the *matrix* $a$. hence $a^{(n)}(x,y) \neq a(x,y)^n$.

Comment: But I thought x and y indicate the size of the matrix, i.e. a(1,2) is the entry of row 1 and column 2. What is  $a(x,y)^n $ then?

Comment: Let's look at an example. $A=( \begin{matrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 5 \end{matrix})$. I think in your last  comment you made a mistake. I suppose you mean that $a^{(2)}(1,2)=12$ and $a(1,2)^2=4$ in this example. So $a^{(n)}(x,y)$ is the (x,y)-entry of the nth matrix power and $a(x,y)^n$ is the nth power of the (x,y)-entry of A. Right?

Comment: yes, I confused myself. you are right.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how I can follow the 3th line of the quote?

Comment: this is quite simple actually, thanks to the limsup. take the subsequence $(a^{n(a+b)}(x,x))^{1/n(a+b)}$. Its liminf is $\ge \alpha^{1/(a+b)}$ because of the inequality. hence the limsup of the sequence $(a^{n}(x,x))^{1/n}$ is $\ge \alpha$.